# Why does this program loop infinitely?

Tags: java

I have the following code (it doesn't matter what it does, but for the curious, it's the start of an implementation of a square bending algorithm).

The problem is, it loops for no reason:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Solution
{
public static class kll
{
    int ni;
    int nj;
    int pi;
    int pj;
    int v;

    kll(){};
}

public static class g
{
    static kll[][] a;
    static int wh;
}

public static void f(int i1,int i2,int j1,int j2)
{
    int nj1,nj2;
    while (g.a[i1][i2].ni!=g.wh && g.a[i1][i2].nj!=g.wh)
    {
        i1=g.a[i1][i2].ni;
        i2=g.a[i1][i2].nj;
    }

    while (g.a[j1][j2].ni!=g.wh && g.a[j1][j2].nj!=g.wh)
    {
        j1=g.a[j1][j2].ni;
        j2=g.a[j1][j2].nj;
    }
    while (j1!=0)
    {
        nj2=g.a[j1][j2].pj;
        nj1=g.a[j1][j2].pi;
        g.a[i1][i2].ni=j1;
        g.a[i1][i2].nj=j2;
        g.a[j1][j2].pi=i1;
        g.a[j1][j2].pj=i2;
        i1=j1;
        i2=j2;
        j1=nj1;
        j2=nj2;
    }
    g.a[i1][i2].ni=g.wh;
    g.a[i1][i2].nj=g.wh;


}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        FileWriter oos1 = new FileWriter("output.txt");
        File inTxt=new File("input.txt");
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(inTxt);
        int input=kbd.nextInt();
        kbd.close();
        int number=(int)Math.pow(4,input);
        g.wh=(int)Math.sqrt(number);

        g.a=new kll[g.wh+1][g.wh+1];

        for(int i=0;i<g.wh+1;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<g.wh+1;j++)
                g.a[i][j]=new kll();

        for(int i=0;i<g.wh;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<g.wh;j++)
            {
                g.a[i][j].ni=g.wh;
                g.a[i][j].nj=g.wh;
                g.a[i][j].pi=0;
                g.a[i][j].pj=0;
                g.a[i][j].v=0;
            }

        int separator=g.wh;
        int half;
        while(separator>1)
        {
            half=separator/2;
            for(int i=0;i<half;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<separator;j++)
                    f(j,i,j,separator-1-i);
            for(int i=0;i<half;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<separator;j++)
                    f(i,j,separator-1-i,j);
            separator=half;
        }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {}
    catch(IOException ex) {}
}

}
```

Where have I gone wrong? That is, where is the infinite loop? What is causing it, and how can I fix it?

EDIT:

I have tried the debugger and it showed me that the infinite loop is here:

```
while (j1!=0)
{
    nj2=g.a[j1][j2].pj;
    nj1=g.a[j1][j2].pi;
    g.a[i1][i2].ni=j1;
    g.a[i1][i2].nj=j2;
    g.a[j1][j2].pi=i1;
    g.a[j1][j2].pj=i2;
    i1=j1;
    i2=j2;
    j1=nj1;
    j2=nj2;
}
```

I don't have any idea why it's infinite. `j1` has got to be zero when it takes `nj1` which is also zero. What's going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: Many Java IDEs have a step-by-step debugger.  Try using that to step through your code and find out where your infinite loop is coming from.

Comment: no, i have never used it, but i will try to, thank you1

Comment: I'd say there's a reason why it's looping: it's unreadable and hard to maintain. More seriously, do try a debugger and to interrupt the program to at least figure out in which loop you are and why it's looping indefinitely.

Comment: Maybe you should ask the person who obfuscated this code?

Comment: What makes you think that `nj1` is 0?

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, j1 is never set to 0, because nj1 is never set to 0, because g.a[ji][j2].pi is never set to 0.

Place breakpoints and inspect g.a[ji][j2].pi -- you will see that it is never 0, given a particular set of arguments.

In particular, you will want to look at the arguments that feed your `f()` function that are causing that function to infinitely loop.

Once you have determined the problematic arguments, you can place an if-statement that causes a breakpoint to be hit before that function is called -- if you have not already determined why `f()` fails.